# Is there a way to do a select statement and union 2 column, replacing any NULL values in one with information from the other

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I'm using Oracle. I have two tables, one which stores Customer ID, Name, billing address; I have another table which stores Store ID, name and address. I need to SELECT (and use a UNION, this is part of an assignment) the CustomerID and their billing address, if their billing address is NULL it needs to replace it the NULL value with the address of the shop the customer is associated with.

The closest I've gotten to what I want is:

```
SELECT s.ordid, C.billingaddress FROM ShopOrder S
INNER JOIN Customer C 
ON C.custid = S.custid

WHERE billingaddress = NULL
UNION 
SELECT S.ordid, S.deliveryaddress FROM ShopOrder S
```

But this just displays the delivery addresses. I have a feeling I may need an Outerjoin or brackets but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared a similar test case for you :

**I have taken two tables, emp and emp1. I want to select the "comm" field from emp, but whenever it is NULL, I will take the value from emp1 which is NOT NULL. This is exactly the rule you mentioned.**

```
SQL> DROP TABLE EMP1 PURGE
  2  /

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE EMP1 AS SELECT * FROM EMP
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> UPDATE EMP1 SET COMM = 9999
  2  /

14 rows updated.

SQL> COMMIT
  2  /

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT e.ename ,
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN e.comm IS NULL
  4      THEN e1.comm
  5      ELSE e.comm
  6    END comm
  7  FROM emp e,
  8    EMP1 E1
  9  WHERE E.EMPNO=E1.EMPNO
 10  /

ENAME            COMM
---------- ----------
SMITH            9999
ALLEN             300
WARD              500
JONES            9999
MARTIN           1400
BLAKE            9999
CLARK            9999
SCOTT            9999
KING             9999
TURNER              0
ADAMS            9999
JAMES            9999
FORD             9999
MILLER           9999

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```